# Translucent Activity does not fit window height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to make a translucent search activity with variable height - `wrap content` on `RecyclerView` to be exact. Unfortunately, I am not able to fit screen height and end up with weird margin at the bottom, as seen on screenshot.

[image: You can see margin even though there is more content in RecyclerView]

Here is my activity layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/WeatherTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/AppBarStyle.Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:logo="@null" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/suggestionsContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyResults"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/not_found"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And theme used for this activity is MainTheme.NoActionBar.Search

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/theme_color_highlight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/theme_text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/theme_color_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MainTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MainTheme.NoActionBar.Search" >
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
</style>
```

Will appreciate any hints on what might cause the problem!

Comment: your parent layout(i.e. android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout) is wrap_content in height, make parent layout android:layout_height="match_parent", probably that might be the problem

Comment: It does help, thanks!